# Al iniciar Navigation Drawer entre con un fragment directamente

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, navigationview

Estoy creando una app la cual tiene un login (main activity) y un registro, al pasar este proceso, paso a entrar a una actividad de Navigation Drawer tengo los fragmentos pero esta se carga en blanco, al pisar las opciones de dicho menu se cargan los fragmentos de forma correcta, mi problema es que quiero que abra ya con el fragment de inicio y que no cargue en blanco.

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.AjustesF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.CalendarioF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.InicioF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.PerfilF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ProfesoresF;

public class Menucentral extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menucentral);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menucentral, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ProfesoresF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new CalendarioF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new AjustesF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PerfilF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Los "fragmentos" te refieres a el contenido dentro del NavigationDrawer en forma de lista?, considera agregar tu código.

Comment: la app "hasta los momentos" me va bien, el problema esta en que el navigation drawer no abre predeterminado el fragment "inicio", la actividad abre en blanco y al desplegar el menu y abrir seleccionar cualquiera el se ejecuta perfectamente, lo que que no quiero es "abrir menu-selec inicio" para ver el inicio, sino que el "inicio" se abra automaticamente

Comment: ok agregué una respuesta Erny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al inicio de tu MainActivity, puedes agregar el fragmento que decidas dentro de `onCreate()`, por ejemplo, suponiendo tu fragmento al iniciar se llama `FragmentInicial`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menucentral);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

/*********Agrega fragmento **************/

   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new FragmentInicial()).commit();

/*********Agrega fragmento **************/

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

la transacción de los demás fragmentos se realizaría al seleccionar un item del menú, lo cual ya tienes implementado:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ProfesoresF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new CalendarioF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new AjustesF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PerfilF()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: WOW!!!! magnifico!!! DISTE EN EL CLAVO!! GRACIAS DE VERDAD GRACIAS estoy que lloro UU tengo 1 semana en esto UU, se que sere un poco molesto pero... existe alguna forma de molestarte en privado? o hacerce "amigo" de alguien en esta red? tengo problemas con sqlite :S

Comment: No Erny en verdad, creo que debiste leer un poquito más, generalmente las aplicaciones inician su activity con un layout o un Fragment default, después mediante el menú realizas la transacción de otros fragmentos.

Comment: tienes razon y sabia que por ese lado era el problema la cuestión esta en que soy una persiona mas practica que lectora y al comenzar SIEMPRE siempre sufro :S  como dije soy nuevo nuevo en esto :S pero gracias de verdad !!

Answer (score 1):

tienes que implemetar este metodo, obviamente haciendo los cambios necesarios

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menucentral);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
setFragment(0)//aqui llamas al metodo que te ddejo abajo y en el metodo, cambias listalibrogragment() por el nombre de tu Fragment, y el "R.id.contentPrincipal" es el id tu content_main_drawer
```

}

```
public void setFragment(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_principal, new ListaLibroFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;

    }
}
```

y llamarlo en tu metodo onCreate() del navigationDrawer

Comment: oks oks GRACIAS GRACIAS POR RESPONDER TAN RAPIDO!! perdon por las mayus pero me emociono en verdad xD, entendi un poco pero quede igual, adiciono mi codigo del navigation para que me guies, podrias ?

Comment: si pone tu codigo

Comment: subido que mas necesitas?

Comment: fijate si te sirve ahi, si te ayude no olvides puntuar

Comment: gracias gracias!! hacen que regresen mis ganas por programar y salir adelante en este mundo!