# Botton Navigation View en todas las pantallas y refrescar home

Tags: java, android

estoy creando una aplicación a la que le he añadido un `Botton Navigation View` pero desconozco si existe alguna forma de que este aparezca en todos los Activity o si por el contrario tendría yo que especificarlo en cada uno de ellos para que aparezca, además de volver a añadir toda su funcionalidad en cada pantalla, ya que esta última opción la veo un poco engorrosa.

La otra pregunta es para el botón Home de dicha barra, le he añadido un botón que sea home para volver al Activity principal cada vez que pulso, de la forma que lo he hecho ha sido con un Intent que vaya a esa propia pantalla, pero no se si hay otro método:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.btnHome:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    break;
```

Dejo el código del Activity que contiene mi Bottom Navigation:

```
package com.isaac.appet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.btnHome:

                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.btnFinder:

                selectedFragment = new FinderFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.btnNotes:

                selectedFragment = new NotesFragment();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmen_container, selectedFragment).commit();

        return true;
    }

};

}
```

Comment: por lo general Bottom Navigation View es para navegar entre fragments: https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

Comment: @armen si, eso he descubierto después de mucho leer. Ahora tengo una duda a ver si me la sabes resolver. Yo tenía un Splash Screen que iba perfecto cuando era un Activity, pero claro, ahora quiero que ese Splash Screen me muestre cuando desaparece el Fragmente de Home, pero ya con el intent no puedo, ¿de que forma puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ese Splash puede ser una activity, de inicio que al terminar el splash con un intent pasas a la activity que tiene el bottom navigation

Comment: @armen pero cuando muestro la activity que tiene el bottom navigation sale en blanco, porque el home está en otra clase que es un fragment, entonces no se si hay alguna forma de que el activity que contiene el botton navigation lance de alguna forma automática el fragment del home

Comment: muestra el codigo java del activity que tiene el bottom navigation. Posiblemente no has establecido con que fragment iniciar esa activity

Comment: pues seguramente jajaja ahí lo he dejado en una respuesta debajo

Comment: para un mejor orden mueve el codigo a la pregunta. Y efectivamente no has asignado el fragment de inicio, esto se realiza en onCreate con fragment transaction. Aquí un ejemplo: FragmentManager ... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36003/al-iniciar-navigation-drawer-entre-con-un-fragment-directamente

Comment: Solo las dos primeras lineas verdad? Las que aparecen después del primer comentario, lo he hecho así y funciona pero a ver si me olvido de añadir algo jajajaja llevo literalmente dos horas entre Google y Stackoverflow en inglés, y no encontraba respuesta, te voy a poner un piso en Nueva York jajajaja

Comment: solo agrega dentro de onCreate y despues de bottomNavigation .., esto: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmen_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

Comment: si, así lo he hecho y funciona, muchas gracias! 